# When I try to change volume with Spotify API, I get error code 403

Tags: python, request, spotify

When I try to change the volume, I get:

```py
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/volume
```

I checked if my `client_id` and `client_secret`, everything seems fine. Also I have premium account.

```py
import requests


from client_secrets import client_id, client_secret

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

# POST
auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    "scope": "user-modify-playback-state",
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
})

# convert the response to JSON
auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

# save the access token
access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=access_token)
}

data = {"volume_percent": 10}
response = requests.put("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/volume",data=data, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: The problem is that is that you are using the Client Credentials Flow. You must use the [**Authorization** Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/), because the code needs to use the [**Authorization** Scope](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/) `user-modify-playback-state`.

Comment: Or alternatively, you can use the Python module SpotiPy, and the Authorization is handled for you.

Comment: I already, have spotipy working, just wanted to try if it works any faster with requests

Answer (score -1):

Several authorization flows are detailed in their [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/) but your request doesn't match any of them. If I understand correctly your app is just a server-side code without any frontend which means that the [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/) is the one that best matches your need. In this flow you don't need to send the client ID and secret in the request body instead, you need to send them in the Authorization header in the following format: `Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>`.

Also, make sure to set the Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as stated in the documentation.

Otherwise, the rest seems fine.

Comment: The problem is that is that Knedl is already using the Client Credentials Flow. Knedl must use the [**Authorization** Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/), because the code needs to use the [**Authorization** Scope](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/) `user-modify-playback-state`.

Comment: You can't use Authorization Code Flow when you are not in the browser because in that flow you need to be redirected to Spotify

Comment: I use SpotiPy, and even though it is a Python module, it works. So, your argument that it won't work, because you aren't in a browser, is false.

Comment: And what happens? how the user authorizes the app for the asked scopes?

Comment: There's a reason I use SpotiPy: that I don't have to deal with it. The fact is that you can't use the endpoint Knedi wants without authorization, and not without that scope.